# Using Cruise Control With No Solution Files

Tags: c#, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I've just joined a team that for whatever reasons do not check in their .sln files into source control (VSS). They Create their local solution files and add the web application projects to it from source control.

I'm trying to show them the beauty of CruiseControl.Net however in the ccnet.config file i'm used to pointing the build tool (DEVENV) at a .sln file.

Does anyone know the best way I could get around this in CruiseControl?

PS. No abuse about using VSS please, we're hopefully moving to SVN soon.

-- Lee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cruise Control will happily compile using [MS Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452.aspx) (`.proj`) files, with which you can build a fairly complete build script.

Also, don't forget that your `.csproj` files follow the `.proj` file format, so at the very basic level you can just point Cruise Control at your `.csproj` files and be done.

p.s. I wouldn't dream of abusing VSS... it's beneath me. You're stuck with what you're stuck with, and I understand how that goes. But you should push for something better if you get the chance. I prefer subversion, personally.

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't build web application projects using MSBuild (as they are not 'real' xml-based-msbuild-projects).

Comment: The asker did write "web application", so I assume he's using a Web Application Project in VS 2008, which definitely has a .csproj file as it's a single compiled .dll delivered in the ./bin folder with only the individual .aspx files left un-compiled. Perhaps you're thinking of a Web Site Project in VS 2008 wherein all .cs files are delivered un-compiled and compiled by ASP.NET. And you're correct, a .csproj file doesn't exist in that scenario. But a .proj file written manually to include all those files can still build them for CC.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i'm trying this next.. and pointing it at the  .csproj file.

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/MsBuild+Task

-- Lee